# Write stdout to a temp file using command line

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, docker, process-substitution

Say for example we wanted to write the env from the host to Docker container, one way would be to use a temp file:

```
env > env_file && docker run --env-file env_file image_name
```

to avoid a temp file, maybe we could use process substitution, but obviously this won't quite work:

```
docker run --env-file <(env) image_name
```

is there some way to write the env output somehow without have to use a temp file?

The error I get is:

> ```
> $ docker run --env-file <(env) redis
>
> docker: poorly formatted environment: variable 'echo "copied to clipboard";' has white spaces.
> See 'docker run --help'.
> ```

Comment: Is there a particular error you saw when using process substitution? Post the same

Comment: well it's looking for filepath, not reading from stdin

Comment: If you're worried about storing the env variables there or space concerns, I suppose a named pipe would be an option, living on your filesystem with 0 bytes actual size: `mkfifo env_pipe`, `env > env_pipe &`, `docker ... --env-file env_pipe`.  Additionally, an *actual* tmp file can be made with `mktemp` which will end up in /tmp/ and disappear on reboot or cleaned up later.

Comment: It looks as if Docker is complaining about the _contents_ of the environment file rather than about not finding it. There is nothing saying that the output of `env` is fit for execution. You may want to investigate using `declare -xp` in `bash` instead, or something that outputs the environment variables in quoted form at least.

Comment: When you run `docker run --env-file <(env) image_name`, the shell runs the `env` command and substitutes its standard output file descriptor device in place of the `<(env)`, so the command actually executed will be something like `docker run --env-file /dev/fd/63 image_name`. But since Docker uses namespaces and whatnot, the `/dev/fd/63` the process reading the environment file (i.e. probably within the container) sees might not be the same as the `/dev/fd/63` your shell creates (outside the container).

Comment: @telcoM that seems most plausible. Probably a bad practice to copy all env vars anyway.